# Зачем нужен IabHelper android?

Tags: in-app-purchases, android, java

Добрый день! Внедряю inn-app Biling в приложение. Пользовался оф. мануалом. Всё работает исправно. Покупки совершаются, строки приходят. Но часто встречал использование IabHelper. 
Собственно вопрос - для чего он нужен и нужен ли вообще?

**P.S.** С покупками в приложении столкнулся впервые.

Comment: Iab расшифровывается как In App Billing. Это класс-хелпер для упрощения работы с ин апп биллингом.

Comment: @Левон, @metalurgus, меня тоже интересует вопрос интеграции данной библиотеки в приложение и принцип организации покупок/продаж. Интересует платное выключение рекламы. Напишите мне, пожалуйста, если есть толковый мануал.

Comment: @web_alex Куда вам написать про толковый мануал? Мне вполне помого http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html